# Having an array of structs as a member of a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Say I have the following struct declarations:

```
struct paragraph
{
    char** line;
    int numLines;
}

struct chapter
{
    struct paragraph** paragraph;
    int numParagraphs;
}

struct book
{
    struct chapter** chapter;
    int numChapters;
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do (and understand) is how I can say something like this:

```
struct book myBook;

myBook.chapter[0].paragraph[0].line[0] = "This is the first line";
```

And have it work. That code gives me the error "Request for member 'paragraph' in something not a structure or union".

I can change the last line to:

```
myBook.chapter[0]->paragraph[0]->line[0] = "This is the first line";
```

And it complies with no errors (including -Wall in the compile statement) but it gives me a segmentation fault.

This shouldn't be too hard to figure out, I would think, but I'm kind of stuck here.

Comment: Why are you using pointer to pointer to struct? I think you just want pointer to struct.

Comment: I want an array of structs

Comment: An array of structs would be `struct paragraph *paragraph;`. `struct paragraph** paragraph` is an array of pointers to paragraphs.

Comment: With C, you have to do all the hard work of allocating memory for your data structures. I don't see any of that here....

Comment: @Barmar that's not an array...

Comment: .... thats a space station! :-P

Comment: @vogomatix for the sake of argument I would even go as far as asserting that pointers have more in common with space stations than with arrays! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your pointers have memory allocated for them, hence, element 0 doesn't exist and results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: So do I need to allocate memory for every struct declaration? I guess I'm just confused on how to do that properly.

Comment: `myBook.chapter = malloc(chapter_count * sizeof(*myBook.chapter));` for example.

Comment: Also, I think you will need only a single pointer paragraph and chapter. Ex. `struct paragraph *paragraph` and `struct chapter *chapter`. You will need to allocate the memory for them using malloc() to make them arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct chapter** chapter;
```

To declare simple array, it is enough to use one '*'. After that you can get any item of the array by index and your first line "myBook.chapter[0].para..." will compile:

```
struct chapter* chapter;
```

Anyway, the program won't work because you have to allocate memory for all arrays that you declared with malloc/calloc or alike function. Otherwise you get segmentation fault error.

Comment: `struct chapter** chapter;` is not a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, strictly to say it not 2d array. I meant that char** is not really simple array that topic started wanted to see (according to his/her first try of array usage via '.').

Comment: if you really meant that, I suggest you update your answer with correct terminology in it. Beginners are already confused enough about arrays and pointers and "array == pointer" is a common misconception that shan't be spread further. thanks.